# Java - How to connect multiple clients to a single server in intranet?

Tags: java, client-server

I have made a chatroom app which consists of a Server and a Client.

Server contains a serverSocket, and each connected client via socket makes a new thread on the server.

Currently I'm using localhost to run both server and client on my mac-

```
    SOCK = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 5555);
```

Is there anyway to make the server available to clients either in intranet or via internet?

[Our Project on GitHub](https://github.com/reetawwsum/Java_ChatRoom)

Comment: Since your local computers are behind a NAT firewall which most probably map multiple local addresses to one public address, you would need a port-forwarding to your local computer where your server runs. I doubt that the network administrator of your college will do that. You could only connect within the local network.

Comment: Isn't there anything I can write in client like 220.xxx.xx.234:Port:192.168.7.xxx:Port or something?